# Making sublabel or subtitle within radioButton

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

Using the code below, I am trying to make two sub-labels or sub-titles (Yes, No) within a radioButton sidebar. It kind of works however I wonder how can I make the "Yes" and "No" bold while removing the their buttons so they look more like sub-titles or sub-labels.

```
radioButtons(
  inputId = "ProjectID",
  label = strong("Select Project:"),
  selected="2",
  choiceNames = c(
    HTML("<strong>Yes<strong>"),
    "2", "7", "9", "14", "15", "16", "23", "25", "26", "40", "42", "48", "55", "70", "76", "81", "94",
    HTML("<strong>No<strong>"),
    "S8", "43", "62", "63", "69", "74", "86", "91", "95"
  ),
  choiceValues = c("",
    "2", "7", "9", "14", "15", "16", "23", "25", "26", "40", "42", "48", "55", "70", "76", "81", "94",
    "",
    "S8", "43", "62", "63", "69", "74", "86", "91", "95"
  )
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider `selectInput` which allows for groups and will work similarly if `multiple = F`:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("value", "Select Project:",
                choices = list(Yes = list("2", "7", "9", "14", "15", "16", "23", "25", "26", "40", "42", "48", "55", "70", "76", "81", "94"),
                               No = list("S8", "43", "62", "63", "69", "74", "86", "91", "95"))
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", input$value)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Can we make the Yes and No bolder?